# Can SOAPUI Test both Sending and Receiving Requests at the same time?

Tags: soapui

We have a need to send a SOAP message from within a testcase and also test what is sent to our mock service at the same time. So something like this:

```
Send SOAP Request -> Webservice
Response <- Webservice
```

20 or 30 seconds later

This is a different request coming to our Mock Service on SOAPUI

```
Mock Service <-Webservice
```

I want to have a test steps for both. Sending the request and getting a response and then expecting a request to our service.

Any ideas?

I started using the tool 1 day ago so I hope my lingo is understandlable.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Mock request step actually does this. and I am able to add assertions and transfer those value to other steps.